# Trigger click event once another trigger is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, callback

Currently I trigger a click event in the following manner.

```
$( "#elem1" ).trigger( "click" );
```

I need to trigger 2 click events, so I simply duplicated the above function as follows.

```
$( "#elem1" ).trigger( "click" );
$( "#elem2" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Unfortunately the second function is invoked before the first click event is complete. So I tried to do this using a callback method:

```
$("#elem1").trigger("click", function() {
    $( "#editLayoutButton" ).trigger( "click" );
    alert('clicked');
});
```

The second click event was never fired, so I added an alert function for debugging purposes. The alert function is never called.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn5022su/)

Comment: What do you do in the first click event? Normally it should finish before the other line.

Comment: Your demo is useless. You need to replicate the problem in demo, namely *"the second function is invoked before the first click event is complete"*. Your current demo doesn't make sense in terms of this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Triggering .click() events, one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026584/jquery-triggering-click-events-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no callback for the trigger method.

You can use a `setTimeout` to make sure the other trigger occurs after the first click trigger.

```
$( "#elem1" ).trigger( "click" );
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('#elem2').trigger('click'); 
},1);
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

---

See also:
[How to run a callback function on a jQuery trigger("click")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519410/how-to-run-a-callback-function-on-a-jquery-triggerclick)
and
[How do I detect a jquery trigger events completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564494/how-do-i-detect-a-jquery-trigger-events-completion)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to put a function in the trigger because it doesnt know what the click does, so there is no callback function for the trigger function. there are 2 options.

1. if you know how long it takes before the first function is done. use the `setTimeout` function
2. use the function that gets triggerd by the first click and check there if it is finished and trigger there the next click function

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
$("#elem1").click( function () {
    $("#elem2").trigger("click");
    alert('clicked');
});
```

You're doing 2 different things.  The first is you are watching for a "click."  Once you get that click, you are "triggering" another click.